# Remove conductive pen trace

Tags: pcb

I repaired a PCB trace with a conductive pen that I now want to remove without damaging the underlying copper.  Is there any solvent that will remove a nickel conductive pen trace?

Comment: Which pen exactly?

Comment: Scalpel and check with ohmmeter.

Comment: nail polish remover

Comment: I currently use Chemtronics Circuit Maker (?) nickel conductive pen.
Does the nail polish remover need a lot of scrubbing?  Would regular acetone work as well?

Comment: I tried acetone and it worked great.